# parallell multiplication of vectors using async C++

Tags: c++, vector, parallel-processing, future, stdasync

I am trying to parallelize a piece of code that multiplies two vectors of complex floats and sums the result. To do this I am trying to use std::async with futures. My idea was to split the vector into 8 parts and perform the multiplication on each of these 8 parts in parallel before summing them for my final result. To do this I create 8 futures each containing a lambda that multiplies two vectors and sums the result. Each future is passed pointers to different positions of the vector which represents the section of the vector this particular future should act on.

However it does not seem to be giving me the speed ups I expected, it has maybe sped this section of the code up by 20-30% but that is it, in addition the load doesn't seem to spread across my cores (4 or 8 with hyperthreading) but rather seems to be all on one core which is at 100%.

I have included the code below. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
size_t size = Input1.size()/8;

std::vector<std::future<complex<float> > > futures;
futures.reserve(8);

for(int i = 0; i<8; ++i)
{
    futures.push_back(std::async( [](complex<float>* pos, complex<float>*pos2, size_t siz)
    {
        complex<float> resum(0,0);
        for(int i = 0; i < siz; ++i)
            resum += pos[i]*pos2[i];
        return resum;
    }, &Input1[i*size], &Input2[i*size], size));
}


complex<float> ResSum(0,0);
for(int i = 0; i < futures.size(); ++i)
    ResSum += futures.at(i).get();
```

Comment: How big are those vectors? You might want to split the input on alignment boundaries. This would probably benefit more from vectorization, and rearrangement of the algorithm so you get most out of the cache.

Comment: Not sure how much it will help but you should do a `reserve` call on `resum` to prevent memory allocations in the thread.

Comment: Don't know if this affects the timing in this particular case, but if `Input1.size()` is not a multiple of 8, the last thread will run off the end of the arrays.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for the input, the size of Input1 is 4096 so the run off issue should be OK. There is already vectorization activated in this code,  im not sure what I would do to the algorithm to improve caching but I welcome advice on this!

Comment: I hate to say it, but this isn't the type of task that's well suited for parallelism. There's too little work for too much memory involved. If the vectors are too large to fit in cache, then it's memory-bound. If the vectors are small enough to fit in cache, then the amount of work may be too small to offset the overhead of spawning threads.

Comment: hmm perhaps you are right, maybe the correct solution is to have the whole multiply & sum of the vector in the lambda  and have different instances of  the lambda being computed in parallel? although im not sure how I would go about this .. :D

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much data you throw at it.

In the following example 4096 entries will be faster with a simple loop. But with 1000*4096 entries the parallel version is faster.

So your results of 20-30% improvement probably just fell in between that range with the hardware in question.

Here is the test program I used.

The first run is the simple loop, the second is from the question and the third uses `std::launch::async`.

```
Plain       From        With
loop        question    launch::async
First       Second      Third
166         1067        607     
166         614         434     
166         523         509     
265993      94633       66231       
182981      60594       69537       
237767      65731       57256
```

Here is the [live result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75db992d227f5221).

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <complex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <ratio>

float get_random()
{
    static std::default_random_engine e;
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0,1); // rage 0 - 1
    return static_cast<float>(dis(e));
}

void do_tests(float val1, float val2, float val3, float val4, int multiplier)
{
    {
        std::vector<std::complex<float>> Input1(4096*multiplier,std::complex<float>{val1,val2});
        std::vector<std::complex<float>> Input2(4096*multiplier,std::complex<float>{val3,val4});
        std::complex<float> ResSum(0,0);
        auto start{std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()};

        size_t size = Input1.size();
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
            ResSum += Input1[i]*Input2[i];
        }

        auto end{std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()};
        auto time_used{end-start};
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(time_used).count() << "\t\t";
    }

    {
        std::vector<std::complex<float>> Input1(4096*multiplier,std::complex<float>{val1,val2});
        std::vector<std::complex<float>> Input2(4096*multiplier,std::complex<float>{val3,val4});
        std::complex<float> ResSum(0,0);
        auto start{std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()};

        size_t size = Input1.size()/8;
        std::vector<std::future<std::complex<float>>> futures;
        futures.reserve(8);

        for (int i = 0; i<8; ++i) {
            futures.push_back(
                std::async(
                    [](std::complex<float>* pos,std::complex<float>*pos2,size_t siz) {
                std::complex<float> resum(0,0);
                for (int i = 0; i < siz; ++i)
                    resum += pos[i]*pos2[i];
                return resum;
            }
                    ,&Input1[i*size],&Input2[i*size],size
                )
                );
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); ++i)
            ResSum += futures.at(i).get();

        auto end{std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()};
        auto time_used{end-start};
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(time_used).count() << "\t\t";
    }


    {
        std::vector<std::complex<float>> Input1(4096*multiplier,std::complex<float>{val1,val2});
        std::vector<std::complex<float>> Input2(4096*multiplier,std::complex<float>{val3,val4});
        std::complex<float> ResSum(0,0);
        auto start{std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()};

        size_t size = Input1.size()/8;
        std::vector<std::future<std::complex<float>>> futures;
        futures.reserve(8);

        for (int i = 0; i<8; ++i) {
            futures.push_back(
                std::async(std::launch::async,
                    [](std::complex<float>* pos,std::complex<float>*pos2,size_t siz) {
                std::complex<float> resum(0,0);
                for (int i = 0; i < siz; ++i)
                    resum += pos[i]*pos2[i];
                return resum;
            }
                    ,&Input1[i*size],&Input2[i*size],size
                )
                );
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); ++i)
            ResSum += futures.at(i).get();

        auto end{std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()};
        auto time_used{end-start};
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(time_used).count() << "\t\t";
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

}

int main()
{
    float val1{get_random()};
    float val2{get_random()};
    float val3{get_random()};
    float val4{get_random()};

    std::cout << "First\t\tSecond\t\tThird\n";

    do_tests(val1, val2, val3, val4, 1);
    do_tests(val1, val2, val3, val4, 1);
    do_tests(val1, val2, val3, val4, 1);
    do_tests(val1, val2, val3, val4, 1000);
    do_tests(val1, val2, val3, val4, 1000);
    do_tests(val1, val2, val3, val4, 1000);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

As written, the call to `std::async` gets the default launch policy of `launch::any`, which allows running all the asyncs on a single thread. To insist on separate threads, pass `launch::async` as the first argument in the call to `std::async`.

Comment: Hey! I have tried the inclusion of this launch::async flag but it makes the code run dramaticallly slower. This perhaps points to a greater flaw in this code?